# WSTP connection does not connect on windows

Tags: kernel, mathlink-or-wstp, windows

I am new in mathematica programming. Actually referring this [link](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/c/WSOpenString.html), I tried to connect to kernel from c++ program on **Windows with visual studio**. I copied all these .exe files in related folder which i used in my code as well. But it does not connect after lots of separate try. this is my code,

```
WSENV env;
WSLINK link;
int error;

env = WSInitialize((WSEnvironmentParameter)0);

link = WSOpenString(env, "E:\\ProgrammingProjects\\PhD\\MathematicaTest\\mathfiles\\MathKernel.exe -mathlink",&error);
int res = WSConnect(link);
```

in this type the returned res is "0" and no connection.

I Also tried WolframKernel.exe

```
link = WSOpenString(env, "E:\\ProgrammingProjects\\PhD\\MathematicaTest\\mathfiles\\WolframKernel.exe -wstp",&error);
int res = WSConnect(link);
```

but this code block at connect function and as it said in documentation it means there is no connection. **Should I do something more before running this code?** Could you help me through this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by checking [.NET examples](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/NETLink/ref/net/Wolfram.NETLink.MathLinkFactory.CreateKernelLink_overload_2.html).

```
lp = WSOpenString(env, "-linkmode launch -linkname \"E:/Software/mathematica/mathkernel.exe\"", &error);

int res = WSConnect(lp);
```